# Passing a char as input for a scanf("%d") breaks my program

Tags: c, scanf

I have a program that involves a menu from which the user can select various options. The selection is handled by a `scanf("%d")`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int menu();

int main
{
    int sel;

    do
    {
        sel = menu ();
    } while (sel != 0);

    return 0;
}

int menu ()
{
    int menuSelect;

    do
    {
        printf(" ------------------Menu------------------\n");
        printf("| 1) Nuova partita                       |\n");
        printf("| 2) Inserisci valori                    |\n");
        printf("| 3) Cancella valori                     |\n");
        printf("| 4) Verifica la soluzione attuale       |\n");
        printf("| 5) Carica e verifica una soluzione     |\n");
        printf("| 6) Riavvia la partita attuale          |\n");
        printf("| 0) Esci                                |\n");
        printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");

        printf("=> "); 
       
        scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
    } while (menuSelect < 0 || menuSelect > 6)

    /* 
    various cases
    */

    return menuSelect;
}
```

When passing an `int` as input it work fine.

But if I pass something else, it turns into an infinite loop.
For example:

input:

```
a
```

output:

```
 ------------------Menu------------------
| 1) Nuova partita                       |
| 2) Inserisci valori                    |
| 3) Cancella valori                     |
| 4) Verifica la soluzione attuale       |
| 5) Carica e verifica una soluzione     |
| 6) Riavvia la partita attuale          |
| 0) Esci                                |
 ----------------------------------------
=> 
 ------------------Menu------------------
| 1) Nuova partita                       |
| 2) Inserisci valori                    |
| 3) Cancella valori                     |
| 4) Verifica la soluzione attuale       |
| 5) Carica e verifica una soluzione     |
| 6) Riavvia la partita attuale          |
| 0) Esci                                |
 ----------------------------------------
=> 
 ------------------Menu------------------
| 1) Nuova partita                       |
| 2) Inserisci valori                    |
| 3) Cancella valori                     |
| 4) Verifica la soluzione attuale       |
| 5) Carica e verifica una soluzione     |
| 6) Riavvia la partita attuale          |
| 0) Esci                                |
 ----------------------------------------
=> 

etc...
```

I would have thought that a `char` would just get ignored by `scanf("%d")`, is the creation of the infinite loop caused by the `scanf` receiving incompatible input or is it something to do with my program?

Is there also some way to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 0):

By typing `a` when an int was expected, nothing was scanned into `menuSelect`. It remains an uninitialized variable, invoking undefined behavior.

You can check the return value of `scanf` and use that to determine whether to continue or not. If `scan_result` is not `1`, then it did not read into `menuSelect`.

```
        int scan_result = scanf("%d", &menuSelect);
    } while (scan_result != 1 || menuSelect < 0 || menuSelect > 6);
```

A very simple program can show you what's happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n;
  int result = scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
6
1
$ ./a.out 
a
0
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if `scanf` input is incorrect, it gets stuck inside input buffer indefinitely. You may try to read it with a string after each erroneous `scanf()`.

```
    if (scanf("%d", &menuSelect) == 0){
        char tmp[20];
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        menuSelect = 0;
    }
```

Comment: If the input is long, this will overflow your buffer and cause bad things to happen.  Better to use `scanf("%*s");` to discard the string, as that's what you actually want.  Or `scanf("%*[\n]");` to dscard everything up to the next newline.